# ViewTreeObserver.OnGlobalLayoutListener on each and every recycler view items to passively resize TextView automatically

Tags: android, kotlin

I have a plain basic recycler view and its adapter.
In the single recycler view row, I got a textView which are floating numbers.
The textView width length shall fixed in proportional sizes, i.e. 30 % of the screen.
I want to put OnGlobalLayoutListener to auto resize text downward passively whenever the text exceed over the separator line
so that it fits in the textView box prepared.
**I don't want WRAP the numbers**

So I add OnGlobalLayoutListener on each ViewHolder and expect to detect & tracing each row items if the costTextView is Overlapped to the separator line.

[image]

**However what happened is it does not resize all rows, but part of items that exposed on user screen only. Example 4-7 does not affected, 8-12 is affected, so on.**

[image]

**MainFragment.kt**

```
import android.os.Bundle
import android.view.LayoutInflater
import android.view.View
import android.view.ViewGroup
import androidx.core.os.bundleOf
import androidx.databinding.DataBindingUtil
import androidx.fragment.app.Fragment
import androidx.navigation.fragment.findNavController
import androidx.recyclerview.widget.DefaultItemAnimator
import androidx.recyclerview.widget.LinearLayoutManager
import androidx.recyclerview.widget.RecyclerView
import com.elliot.financetracker.databinding.MainFragmentBinding

class MainFragment : Fragment() {
    companion object {
        private val TAG = "HomeFragment"
    }

    private lateinit var thisView: View
    private lateinit var binding: MainFragmentBinding
    private var cashList: ArrayList<Cash> = ArrayList()
    private lateinit var recyclerView: RecyclerView
    private lateinit var mAdapter: CashAdapter

    init {
        cashList = prepareMovieData()
    }

    override fun onCreateView(
        inflater: LayoutInflater,
        container: ViewGroup?,
        savedInstanceState: Bundle?
    ): View? {

        binding =
            DataBindingUtil.inflate<MainFragmentBinding>(
                inflater,
                R.layout.main_fragment, container, false
            )
        thisView = binding.root
        return thisView
    }

    override fun onViewCreated(view: View, savedInstanceState: Bundle?) {
        super.onViewCreated(view, savedInstanceState)
        recyclerView = binding.rvCash
        mAdapter = CashAdapter(cashList, action)
        val mLayoutManager: RecyclerView.LayoutManager = LinearLayoutManager(thisView.context)
        recyclerView.layoutManager = mLayoutManager
        recyclerView.itemAnimator = DefaultItemAnimator()
        recyclerView.adapter = mAdapter
    }

    private val action = object : CashAdapter.ClickedListener {
        override fun onItemClick(cash: Cash) {
            val bundle = bundleOf("cash" to cash)
            this@MainFragment.findNavController().navigate(R.id.edit_frag, bundle)
        }
    }

    private val actionAddNewRecord = object : View.OnClickListener {
        override fun onClick(v: View?) {
            val arg = Bundle()
            arg.putInt("sss", 43)
            this@MainFragment.findNavController().navigate(R.id.edit_frag, arg)
        }
    }

    private fun prepareMovieData(): ArrayList<Cash> {
        for (i in 0..29) {
            cashList.add(
                Cash(
                    "-2000000000000000000000000.00",
                    "Action & Adventure $i"
                )
            )
        }

        return cashList
    }

}
```

**CashAdapter.kt**

```
import android.graphics.Rect
import android.util.Log
import android.view.LayoutInflater
import android.view.View
import android.view.ViewGroup
import android.view.ViewTreeObserver
import android.widget.TextView
import androidx.recyclerview.widget.RecyclerView
import com.elliot.financetracker.CashAdapter.CashViewHolder
import com.elliot.financetracker.databinding.CashListRowBinding
import com.elliot.financetracker.utils.*

//import com.example.recyclerviewbinding.databinding.MovieListRowBinding;
class CashAdapter(
    private val cashList: List<Cash>,
    private val clickedAction: ClickedListener
) : RecyclerView.Adapter<CashViewHolder>() {

    companion object {
        private var TAG = "CashAdapter"
    }

    inner class CashViewHolder(private val binding: CashListRowBinding) :
        RecyclerView.ViewHolder(binding.root) {
        var positionss: Int = -1
        fun bind(cash: Cash, clickedAction: ClickedListener, positionss: Int) {
            this.positionss = positionss
            binding.cash = cash
            binding.cvCashView.setOnClickListener {
                clickedAction.onItemClick(binding.cash!!)
            }
// ---------- NOTE HERE I ADD GLOBAL LAYOUT LISTENER ---------------------------------------------
            this.binding.cvCashView.viewTreeObserver.addOnGlobalLayoutListener(globalObserver)
            binding.executePendingBindings()
        }

        private val globalObserver = object : ViewTreeObserver.OnGlobalLayoutListener {
            override fun onGlobalLayout() {
                val overlapped = isOverlapped(binding.tvItemCost, binding.separatorCost)
                if (overlapped) {
                    Log.d(CashAdapter.TAG, "${CashAdapter.TAG}: isOverlapping : $positionss")
                    binding.tvItemCost.textSize = resizeTextDown(binding.tvItemCost)
                    // always assumed values in SP units
                } else {
                    Log.d(CashAdapter.TAG, "${CashAdapter.TAG}: isNotOverlapping : $positionss")
                }
            }
        }

        private fun resizeTextDown(target: View): Float {
            val t = target as TextView
            val z = t.textSize
            val a = z.pxToSp()
            val b = a - 2.0F
            // leave it as SP unit will do**
            return b
        }
    }

    interface ClickedListener {
        fun onItemClick(cash: Cash)
    }

    fun isOverlapped(tvItemCost: View, g20: View): Boolean {
        val firstPosition = IntArray(2)
        val secondPosition = IntArray(2)
        tvItemCost.getLocationOnScreen(firstPosition)
        g20.getLocationOnScreen(secondPosition)

        val rectFirstView = Rect(
            firstPosition[0],
            firstPosition[1],
            firstPosition[0] + tvItemCost.measuredWidth,
            firstPosition[1] + tvItemCost.measuredHeight
        )
        val rectSecondView = Rect(
            secondPosition[0],
            secondPosition[1],
            secondPosition[0] + g20.measuredWidth,
            secondPosition[1] + g20.measuredHeight
        )

        return rectFirstView.intersect(rectSecondView)
    }

    // plain basic recycler view adapter's methods
    override fun onCreateViewHolder(parent: ViewGroup, viewType: Int): CashViewHolder {
        val layoutInflater = LayoutInflater.from(parent.context)
        val binding = CashListRowBinding.inflate(layoutInflater, parent, false)
        return CashViewHolder(binding)
    }

    override fun onBindViewHolder(holder: CashViewHolder, position: Int) {
        val cash = cashList[position]
        holder.bind(cash, clickedAction, position)
    }

    override fun getItemCount(): Int {
        return cashList.size
    }
}
```

**cash_list_row.xml**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<layout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools">

    <data>

        <variable
            name="cash"
            type="com.elliot.financetracker.Cash" />
    </data>

    <androidx.cardview.widget.CardView
        android:id="@+id/cv_cash_view"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_margin="0dp"
        android:foreground="?android:attr/selectableItemBackground"
        android:clickable="true"
        android:focusable="true"
        app:cardBackgroundColor="@color/colorLightGreen"
        app:cardElevation="10dp"
        app:cardCornerRadius="@dimen/default_card_corner_radius"
        app:cardUseCompatPadding="true">

        <androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:padding="10dp">

            <TextView
                android:id="@+id/tv_description"
                android:layout_width="0dp"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:padding="10dp"
                android:text="@{cash.description}"
                app:layout_constraintLeft_toLeftOf="parent"
                app:layout_constraintRight_toLeftOf="@id/g_20"
                app:layout_constraintTop_toBottomOf="@id/tv_date"
                tools:text="Item description Item description Item description Item description" />
            <androidx.constraintlayout.widget.Guideline
                android:id="@+id/g_20"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:orientation="vertical"
                app:layout_constraintGuide_percent="0.7"/>
            <View
                android:id="@+id/separator_cost"
                android:layout_width="1dp"
                android:layout_height="0dp"
                android:padding="20dp"
                android:background="@android:color/darker_gray"
                app:layout_constraintLeft_toRightOf="@id/g_20"
                app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent"
                app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent"/>
            <TextView
                android:id="@+id/tv_item_cost"
                android:layout_width="0dp"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:padding="10dp"
                android:text="@{cash.amountString}"
                android:gravity="center_vertical"
                app:layout_constraintRight_toRightOf="parent"
                app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent"
                app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent"
                tools:text="RM -2000000000.00" />

<!--            removed out ...........-->


        </androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout>
    </androidx.cardview.widget.CardView>
</layout>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This can be perfectly solved by the auto resizing feature of TextView

use something like this

```
        <TextView
            android:layout_width="100dp"
            android:layout_height="40dp"
            android:maxLines="1"
            android:text="hello world google"
            app:autoSizeTextType="uniform"
            app:autoSizeMinTextSize="1sp"
            app:autoSizeMaxTextSize="25sp"
            android:gravity="center_vertical"
            />
```

Comment: how to detect if its overlapp? I want it keep resize until it doesn't overlap the separator line, how android determine which TextSize to use when it specified in your way

Comment: @elliotching just use your constraint layout to constraint the width of TextView to be 30% of screen, it's the same. Set app:autoSizeMaxTextSize to your preferred text size, and when there is not enough space, text size will automatically be adjusted to smaller and the text will fill up the 30% space

Comment: wait, does this method support API level 25 and below?

Comment: @elliotching This feature is part of the support library so yes it supports low versions of android